# BIML calling a stored procedure in C# using SSIS project parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, biml

I am new to BIML. I am stuck at the point where I want to call a SQL Server stored procedure in C# and want to pass SSIS project parameter in the stored procedure as a parameter.

For example -

```
<# string sSQL1 = "Exec dbo.USP_ProcName 'p1'";#>

<# DataTable tbl1 = ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(DBConnectionStr,sSQL1); #>

<# foreach (DataRow row in tbl1.Rows){ #>
<Package PackageName="<#=row["PackageName"]#>" />
...
<# } #>
```

In the above example I want to use SSIS project parameter say, `@[Project::Param1]` rather than the constant value `p1`, but I am not getting it right and keep getting syntax errors all the time.

Could someone please help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit you question to include the code you tried for the parameter as well as the exact error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the results of your stored procedure to build a `DataTable` that is then used to create your SSIS packages via Biml.  As far as I am aware, this is not possible.

If you want to have a dynamic element within your actual Biml script, you need to have those values available to reference either in a metadata file or a database somewhere you can connect to and retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party but if anyone else wonders this is actually possible. The following code should work fine:

```
<# 
    string _queryString;
    DataTable _sprocResultSetDT;
    _queryString = string.Format("Exec dbo.MySproc {0}", "InsertParamValueHere");

    _sprocResultSetDT = ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable (_myConnectionString,_queryString); 

    foreach (DataRow row in _sprocResultSetDT.Rows)
    {
#>
    <Package PackageName="<#=row["PackageName"]#>" />

<#  } #> <!-- end of foreach loop -->
```

Don't forget to set NOCOUNT on inside the sproc if it's returning multiple messages as it won't work otherwise.